# Foreign key array in hsqldb

Tags: hsqldb

I have a column of type integer array `GENRE INTEGER ARRAY NOT NULL`, each value of which must be a foreign key. I tried this `FOREIGN KEY(SELECT * FROM GENRE) REFERENCES PUBLIC.GENRE(ID)` but obviously it won't work. Help how this can be implemented in HSQLDB.

Comment: Don't de-normalize - especially if you need foreign keys. Create a proper one-to-many relationship

Comment: Maybe I'm not thinking right but what's wrong with just `FOREIGN KEY(GENRE) REFERENCES PUBLIC.GENRE(ID)`?

Comment: @MZ it won't work because `PUBLIC.GENRE(ID)` is not an array

Comment: This can't be done with FOREIGN KEY. You can write INSERT and UPDATE triggers that check each element of the array is an existing ID.